# ES-Lint complains on used props values, when it's in use

Tags: vuejs3, eslint

Given this following Vue3 sfc code:

```
<template>
    <div>{{msg}}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        msg: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Hello world'
        }
    })
</script>
```

ES-Lint is complaining that the `props is assigned a value but never used`. We know also that the options passed to defineProps ('msg' in this case) will be hoisted out of setup into module scope, so the syntax is correct.
I don't want to disable the `no-unused-vars` ES-lint rule, nor do I wish to dismiss it by using an ES-lint ignore comment, so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this error was caused due to incompatibility between my devenvironment and ESLint's current parsing capabilities.

To fix this (plus some other eslint errors that occured), I added the following package to the project:
`yarn add -D babel-eslint`

then added this `Parsing` option til my `.eslingrc.js` file:
`parser: 'babel-eslint'`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to assign the output of `defineProps` to a variable if you want to use the values within your `script setup`. For use within the `template`, it is enough to declare the props by just calling `defineProps`.

This means that the following would suffice:

```html
<template>
    <div>{{msg}}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
    defineProps({
        msg: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Hello world'
        }
    })
</script>
```

Strangely enough, this is not mentioned in the official documentation; both [Props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html) and [<script setup> | defineProps() & defineEmits()](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) make no mention of it. It is through following instructions from linters that this becomes apparent.